# Update field based on Compound select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement That I need to turn into an Update.
I need to update a particular unix time field to January 1, 2016.
I have to select the records using a compound select statement.

```
Update archive_queue set  archive_time = 1451606400

FROM 

select recordings.(star), archive_queue.(star)

from
recordings, archive_queue

where 
recordings.device_alias = '70285' and recordings.keepdays = 120

and recordings.ident = archive_queue.rec_ident
```

The above gives me a syntax error. The select gives me the records that I need to update. I looked at some examples here, but can't figure out the proper syntax based on my needs. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the select and only have one FROM statement:

```
Update archive_queue set archive_time = 1451606400
from recordings, archive_queue
where recordings.device_alias = '70285' and recordings.keepdays = 120
and recordings.ident = archive_queue.rec_ident
```